# open a page in new tab and load different URL in old window

Tags: javascript, forms, perl, window.open

I am submitting a form using in `action=abc.pl` and abc.pl contains the code for opening the new tab and loading different URL on the same page. Here is the code how I am doing (in abc.pl)

```
window.open('$thisPage')
window.location.href='$nextPage';
```

But the `window.open` opens in new window instead of new Tab.

Comment: You can't control wether `window.open` will open a new tab or a new window, that's completely up to the browser.

Comment: But I created a dummy/test html file which will make the form submit in new tab and load different URL in old window. It works!!!

Comment: I tried _blank, _newtab but still I get window.open in new window. I am testing it in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

as per the previous question on StackOverflow: [Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window) using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript)

```
function open_in_new_tab(url )
{
  var win=window.open(url, '_blank');
  win.focus();
}
```

or

```
$('a').click(function() {
  $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

Comment: Don't copy answer from other questions, just link to them in comments (and close this question, if possible).

Comment: Ahh, ok, but how does one close the question?

Comment: You must have at least [3000 rep](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions).

Answer (score 1):

use second param to specify window name:

```
window.open('page.html','newtaborsomething');
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: Don't recommend w3schools.com as a reference. It's full of errors, see http://w3fools.com

Comment: Yeah, probably you're right. I took first reference I found :]

Comment: I tried _blank, _newtab but still I get window.open in new window. I am testing it in Chrome.

Comment: I posted this question earlier. I added a setTimeOut("function(), 2000) on button submit and on that "function()" call, I added window.open(url1, _blank) and window.location.href=URL2